# Redirect electron popup to BrowserView

Tags: node.js, electron

When a popup is created I'd like to display it in a BrowserView.
Is there a way of piping the entire popup request into a BrowserView?

The example below works for simple urls but not for more complex popups (eg window.open creates an about:blank page and uses document.write to generate content). Can be tested with "Method #1.1" on https://webbrowsertools.com/popup-blocker/.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, BrowserView } = require('electron')

function createWindow() {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  })
  mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window', (event, url, frameName, disposition, options, additionalFeatures) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const view = new BrowserView()
    mainWindow.setBrowserView(view)
    view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 800 })
    view.webContents.loadURL(url)
  })

  mainWindow.loadURL("https://webbrowsertools.com/popup-blocker/")
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})
```